# Good clean template based on HTML5 and ready for mobile/flexible/adaptive design

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

Can you recommend a good clean template for Magento 1.7 that is based on HTML5, ready for mobile screens, using flexible/adaptive design, and which works on normal desktops as well? It doesn't have to be free (as in beer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this http://bootstrapped.magenthon.com/ to be a good clean staring point.

Google for responsive magento themes, there are many ;)

Comment: In the meantime the site is closed unfortunately.